# Is it possible to say that every point $P$ in $C(ℚ)$ other than the 'basis' is of finite order?

Tags: elliptic-curves

Let $C$ an elliptic curve over $\mathbb Q$. Assume that the rank of $C(ℚ)$ is equal to $r$. Then the cardinality of a maximal independent set in $C(ℚ)$ is $r$, thus there exists $r$ independent points ${P_1,P_2,\dots,P_r}$ of infinite order in $C(ℚ)$, i.e., $P_{k}=(x_{k},y_{k})\in\mathbb Q^2,\ k=1,..,r$ (we ignor the torsion part of $C(ℚ)$ to use the canonical height) such that if $∑_{k=1}^{r}α_{k}P_{k}=0$, then $α_{k}=0$ for all $k=1,..,r$.

My **question** is: Is it possible to say that every point $P$ in $C(ℚ)$ other than ${P_1,P_2,\dots,P_r}$ is of finite order?

Comment: But the multiples of those infinite order elements will also be of infinite order.

Comment: So, how I can prove this result.

Comment: What result? That any multiple of an element of infinite order has infinite order?

Comment: Yes, this is the result .

Comment: This is a general result about groups (so nothing to do with this coming from elliptic curves), and an easy exercise.

Comment: Ok, and thank you very much.

Comment: The group $C(\Bbb Q)$ is isomorphic to a group $T\times \Bbb Z^r$, where $T$ is a finite group. Then, almost tautologically, any element in the infinite set $T\times \Bbb Z^r$ which is not in the finite set $T\times 0$ has infinite order. (Else such an element would have finite order, thus being in $T\times 0$. If the second component is not $0$, then its projection on $\Bbb Z^r$ also has finite order, contradiction.)