# A strong form of the Nagell-Lutz theorem

Tags: elliptic-curves

The motivation of this question can be found in

[Is it possible to say that every point $P$ in $C(ℚ)$ other than the 'basis' is of finite order?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349105/is-it-possible-to-say-that-every-point-p-in-c-other-than-the-basis-is-o)

Given the elliptic curve: $$C:y²=x³+ax+b$$

for $a,b∈ℤ$.

Let $O$ be the identity element of $C(ℚ)$. I know about the Nagell-Lutz theorem [T. Nagell, Solution de quelque problèmes dans la théorie arithmétique des cubiques planes du premier genre, Wid. Akad. Skrifter Oslo I (1935), No. 1, 1-25, E. Lutz, Sur l'equation $y²=x³-Ax-B$ dans les corps $p$-adic, J. Reine Angew. Math. 177 (1937), 238-247.] in its explicit form. However, I found a **strong form of the Nagell-Lutz theorem** saying that if $T∈C(ℚ)^{tors}$, then $2T=O$. I do not understand how I can obtain the formula $2T=O$ from the standard Nagell-Lutz theorem.

Comment: Where did you find this "strong form of the Nagell Lutz theorem"? The curve $y^2 = x^3 - 432x + 8208$ has a point $T=(-12,108)$ of order $5$.

Comment: @ÁlvaroLozano-Robledo: Please see http://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahmki/pofo.pdf

Comment: I do not see anywhere a statement that says "If $T\in C(\mathbb{Q})^\text{tors}$, then $2T=\mathcal{O}$". Notice the **OR ELSE** $y^2| D$.

Comment: @ÁlvaroLozano-Robledo: Thank you very much for your nice answer in (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349922/how-i-can-express-x-yg-by-using-the-r-independent-points-p-1-p-2-ldots) . How I can express the point at infinity (the identity element of $C(ℚ)$) in that representation.

Comment: $\mathcal{O}=0\cdot P_1+\cdots+0\cdot P_r + \mathcal{O}$.

Comment: @ÁlvaroLozano-Robledo: Ok and thank you very much.